# SQL Error(1166) : Incorrect column name 'id'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, heidisql

I am new to yii and heidiSQL while am creating new table i get this error,so help me to solve this error

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id ` INT(45) NULL,
    `username ` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `pwd_hash` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `fname` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `lname` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `gender` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    INDEX `PRIMARY KEY` (`id `),
    INDEX `UIQUE KEY` (`username `)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I can't able to create new table in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed at the end of column's definition, must be:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(45) NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `pwd_hash` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `fname` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `lname` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `gender` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    INDEX `PRIMARY KEY` (`id`),
    INDEX `UNIQUE KEY` (`username`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

You have same error for `username`.

Comment: "Spaces are not allowed into columns definition": That's a bit misleading, spaces are allowed into column definitions (even though they are not recommended). Spaces are not allowed at the end of a column name though, source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit strange.  You have spaces at the end of the names (for `id` and `username`).  This seems to be causing the problem, even though the escaped names are used consistently (this is documented in the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)).  This works:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(45) NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `pwd_hash` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `fname` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `lname` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `gender` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    INDEX `PRIMARY KEY` (`id`),
    INDEX `UIQUE KEY` (`username`)
);
```

I would expect the escaped characters to work.  However, spaces at the end of the names is a bad idea, so remove them.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f00c0) is a SQL Fiddle.

I also expect that you intend this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `pwd_hash` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `fname` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `lname` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `gender` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE (`username`)
);
```

Your original table definition created two indexes called "PRIMARY KEY" and "UIQUE".  It did not declare a primary key or a unique constraint.

There is no need to have a number like 45 after `int`.

Comment: misspelled `UNIQUE` in firsr query

Comment: @PathikVejani . . . That makes no difference, because it is the name of an index, not a declaration of uniqueness.

Comment: "Database, table, and column names cannot end with space characters." source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html